# K-Means Clustering Letter Grades

Tags: python, k-means

I am working on an assignment that requires a basic implementation of the k-means clustering algorithm in python. The data we are working with has a raw grade which is numerical and a raw letter grade that is not-numerical. We are supposed to edit code given in lecture to complete this assignment. I keep getting an error that a string cannot be converted to a float and I understand this but am unsure how to proceed. We have not discussed label encoding, so I presume it is not allowed for the assignment, additionally we cannot use k-modes because it has not been taught. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics

grades = pd.read_csv('grades.csv')
raw_grades = pd.DataFrame(grades, columns = ['raw grade', 'raw letter'])
raw_grades
np.random.seed(5)
myKMeans=KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(raw_grades)
labels = kmeans.labels_
labels[0:20]
```

raw_grades looks like this:

```
raw grade   raw letter
```

0   56.1    F
1   60.1    D=
2   60.4    D=
3   63.1    D=
4   64.4    D

The Error message I am getting is:
    `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
     last)
     <ipython-input-23-f444641587d3> in <module>
     1 np.random.seed(5)
     2 X = raw_grades[['raw grade','raw letter']]
     ----> 3 myKMeans=KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(X)
     4 labels = kmeans.labels_
     5 labels[0:20]
     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py in 
     fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
     970                 tol=self.tol, random_state=random_state, 
     copy_x=self.copy_x,
     971                 n_jobs=self.n_jobs, algorithm=self.algorithm,
     --> 972                 return_n_iter=True)
     973         return self
     974 
     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py in 
     k_means(X, n_clusters, sample_weight, init, precompute_distances, n_init, 
     max_iter, verbose, tol, random_state, copy_x, n_jobs, algorithm, 
     return_n_iter)
     310     order = "C" if copy_x else None
     311     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=[np.float64, 
     np.float32],
     --> 312                     order=order, copy=copy_x)
     313     # verify that the number of samples given is larger than k
     314     if _num_samples(X) < n_clusters:
     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in 
     check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, 
     copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, 
     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
     494             try:
     495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
     --> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, 
     order=order)
     497             except ComplexWarning:
     498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"
     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in 
     asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
     ---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 
     ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A+'`

Comment: Can you please post an example of your dataset, what `raw_grades` looks like, and the exact traceback of the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you need to be clustering the raw letter grade too?

Comment: Yes, the k = 5 is representative of the distinct letter grades A, B, C, D, F, where the + and - are not taken into consideration. I know that my program should label those as 0-4, but am unsure of how to do that.